# Get names of all child-elements of a node in Xml-Deserialization

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I got the following XML-Structure:

```xml
<Root>
    <Element Attribute="attibute">
        <ElementINeedNameOf />
        <AnotherElementINeedNameOf />
    </Element>
</Root>
```

I am trying to read the names of the child-element of `element`?
Therefor I am using `System.Xml.Serialization` to read the other elements/attributes but I'm unable to read the names of it's child elements.

Thank you.

Comment: Usually *"Is there a way to...."* questions show a lack of trying. Please show what you have tried to do and research

Comment: You can always traverse the hierarchy of an `XmlDocument` yourself.

Comment: `System.Xml.Serialization` is about serializing in-memory objects to XML (and deserializing them back). Using it to parse XML is probably not the best approach. Consider using the `System.Xml.Linq` namespace (starting point: `XDocument` class).

Comment: Yes, there is a way for perverts. You can use [XmlSerializer.UnknownNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.unknownnode(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is posible by selecting the parent element with `XmlAnyElement`.

The following code shows an example solution:

```
[XmlAnyElement("Element")]
public XmlElement Elements{ get; set; }

[XmlIgnore]
public List<string> ElementNames
{
    get
    {
        var elementNames = new List<string>();
        if (Elements != null && Elements.HasChildNodes)
        {
            elementNames.AddRange(from XmlNode elementsChildNode in Elements .ChildNodes select elementsChildNode.Name);
            return elementNames ;
        }
        else
        {
            //return empty List
            return tagNames;
        }
    }
}
```